How to properly organize table schema for data with "inheritable" properties?
I came with some background in C++ so let me clarify the "inheritable" properties in context of my question.
I have data which is used to setup and control some equipment (so-called "instrument methods", or "method properties" in my vendor's terminology). I have different equipment from different vendors, however, most of the properties are just the same.
Because now I deal only with single instrument type I store all of the method properties directly in one table where each column represents some property while rows contain all necessary data for single "instrument method" record. For example, my columns may be the following: temperature, flow, percent_b, gas_flow, gas_type. But soon I will be dealing with several types of instruments so this question naturally arises.
Let's review the following example.

Method of equipment B contains (b) all of the properties of the method of equipment A (a) plus some extra own parameters (b1). So I can say that A is a direct ancestor of B: A -> B; b = a + b1.
Method of equipment C contains (c) only some of the properties of the method of equipment A (a1) plus some extra own parameters (c1). So I can say that A and C both have common ancestor X in the past: X -> ... -> ... -> A and X -> ... -> ... -> C; c = a1 + c1

Case number 1 represents B being direct mod/upgrade of A (e. g. instruments from the same vendor, just consequent models) while case number 2 represents C being in the same class of instruments as A (even from different vendors but pretty much the same).
I know how to easily implement this with class hierarchy in C++ with just adding extra fields and other data structures where needed but I have no clue how to properly implement this in case of DB tables (if that's important I'm using MariaDB).
As for now I have an idea of possible solution. I've decided to store data for specific instrument models in separate specialized tables, e. g.:

Table MODEL_A contains the following columns: id, temperature, flow, percent_b
Table MODEL_A1 contains the following columns: id, temperature, flow, percent_b, percent_c, percent_d
Table MODEL_B contains the following columns: id, temperature, gas_flow, gas_type

Also I need to store enumeration of supported equipment types (instrument models, in other words) in separate table. Finally, instead of storing all of possible data in one basic table (like with an example at the very beginning) I should store just the following rows of data in it: id, instrument_type, method_id. And here arises other complication. If I use only three columns - ID, reference to the instrument type (which is stored in separate table), reference to the actual data row in method table for specific equipment type - there should be some mechanism to ensure data consistency. I know how to apply foreign key constraints in simple cases (the whole column refers to another in second table) but I don't know how to tie these constraints with one extra constraint - selection of instrument type. Imagine that: end user of DB decides to change equipment type of the record in basic table. That action can invalidate foreign key reference because now we should refer to another table at all and it may (and, most likely, will) not contain proper data at old ID reference. I can prohibit changing instrument type at all, though, it isn't convenient and practical (much better solution would be to make necessary actions in GUI - I can highlight incompatible fields and hint next steps for end user). But in any case I can't leverage the benefit of using ON DELETE and ON UPDATE clauses together with the whole foreign keys idiom because different rows in my basic methods table will refer to the different tables in DB which AFAIK is not supported in MariaDB (or any other RDBMS). It looks like I shall track the whole integrity by hand in my backend/frontend code.
So, I have the following questions:

Is such approach viable at all?
Is there a way to have references to different tables for a different rows of data?
Is there much better way to implement this in a RDBMS like MariaDB?
Are there RDBMSes much more suitable for such a task?


HI, this site works best with one question per post.

Yes, I got it. But I think in this case all of sub-questions are closely tied together. Main problem lies in a proper way to handle hierarchy using RDBMS features

All proper rdbms work the same way, so there is no effective difference in this case. No rdbms cares how well the data is designed or whether any constraints are applied, but they will help you if you set it up correctly.
You basically describe the object-relational mismatch, where you try to super-impose class design onto a relational structure, which does not always work well. You can have a single table with many columns, adding a new one each time a new "property" is required. I have seen many databases designed like this. Most columns will be null and, for each thingy, you have to ask for (select) the correct properties (fields), which can get a bit clumsy over time.
Based on what I think you are doing, my preferred way would be a list (table) of class types and a list of property types, both of which can be extended as required. You then need a simple link table to associate properties with classes, where one class can have many properties, but each property exists only once per class. This table would need class id and property id as the primary key and property value(s) field(s).
If it handles actual readings, then you then need an "objects" list (table), with one record for each physical piece of equipment, with name, id, type and other relevant features. Finally it needs to data readings/values table, with a set of properties for each piece of equipment.

I've thought about one wide table with a lot of columns for each property but decided that this is not well-scalable and easy to maintain. On the other hand my attempt to translate C++ class hierarchy to the RDBMS seems to lead to a bunch of tables interconnected with each other without fancy foreign keys feature (because of complex relationships between them based on a type field) which is a bit clumsy too. But I see that your suggestion much closer to the latter approach which I was thinking about. So, if manual integrity control in backend is inevitable - well, I'll try to stick with it
